# Is there negation syntax for git add's filepattern?

Tags: git

Suppose I want to use `git add` (or some other command line directive - I cannot use .gitignore) to add all files EXCEPT for a *.hi file. Is there a way to do this? So far I have tried:

`git add '!*.hi'`

`git add '!(*.hi)'`

As I understand it, this is how you specify a negation in glob syntax, and it's also how you do it in .gitignore. Yet for both these commands, I receive the error `fatal: [pattern] did not match any files`. For what it's worth, I'm running these commands from Windows Powershell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pure Git way would be to add them all and then remove those files you don’t want from the index again:

```
git add .
git rm --cached *.hi
```

The `--cached` is required to remove them only from the index; otherwise you would delete those files. Note that `git rm` will always “add a removal” to the index, so this is probably not what you want in case the files are tracked. Then you should use `git reset` as Klas Mellbourn suggested in the comments:

```
git add .
git reset -- *.hi
```

Comment: Instead of that last line you could also do `git reset HEAD -- *.hi`

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Good point! That’s actually the only way to do it if the `.hi` files are already tracked.

Answer (score 5):

The exclusion pattern is

```sh
git add ':!*.hi'
```

note the colon.

Tested in PowerShell with `git version 2.28.0.windows.1`

I found [this answer to how to use the exclusion pattern in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977195/git-add-files-which-do-not-match-a-pattern) useful

Comment: "note the semicolon" There is no semicolon.

Comment: @matt sorry I meant colon

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, this works:

```
git add $(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Exclude '*.hi')
```

Comment: Not required, `':!*.hi'` is a Git pathspec and thus portable.