# Git add files which do not match a pattern

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

In Git, while adding files to a commit, we can add all files matching a pattern like so:

`git add **Component**`

I find this feature pretty useful to quickly add lots of files with similar names.

For example, If all my files are named based on components, then I can add all changes I did to a component quickly.

Similarly, is there a way in git to add all files to commit *excluding* files matching a pattern?

Something like:

`git add *.java --exclude **Component1**`

So that I can all my java file changes except the changes that I made to the files of component1?

Comment: that sounds more like something you would solve with bash to call xargs. Something like `blah blah | produce list of files | xargs git add`

Comment: Sounds like a job for find. Bash might have a no match glob; zsh almost certainly does

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try one of

```
git add *.java ':(exclude):**Component1**'
git add *.java ':!**Component1**'
```

Any pathspec beginning with a colon is a [magic pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec). `exclude` is one of them.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me: `git add *.java ':!**Component1**'`